# JS occasionally fails to hide content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm running a series of animations on children divs and siblings whenever a div is clicked that causes containers to resize and content to hide and show. For some reason when clicking through the animation, the animation will occur perfectly however content will fail to be hidden.

There's 2 parts to this. A function that reverts everything back to the original state (closeService). In this function, the part commented as "DROP DOWN INFO" will ocassionally fail to fire.

```
function closeService() {

    $('.graphic-wrapper').animate({ "width": "275px"}, 500);
    $('.div-1').animate({ "width": "25%" }, 500);
    $('.div-2').animate({ "width": "25%" }, 500);
    $('.div-3').animate({ "width": "25%" }, 500);
    $('.div-4').animate({ "width": "25%" }, 500);
    $('.graphic-1').animate({"height": "200px"}).attr("src", "images/svg-icons/1.svg");     
    $('.graphic-2').animate({"height": "200px"}).attr("src", "images/svg-icons/2.svg");
    $('.graphic-3').animate({"height": "220px"}).attr("src", "images/svg-icons/3.svg");
    $('.graphic-4').animate({"height": "170px"}).attr("src", "images/svg-icons/4.svg");
    $('.services-content').hide();

    // DROP DOWN INFO
    $('.dropdown-1').hide();
    $('.dropdown-2').hide();
    $('.dropdown-3').hide();
    $('.dropdown-4').hide();
    $('.dropdown-info').hide();
    $('.services-content').hide();

    setTimeout ( function() {
        $('.dropdown-default').fadeIn();
        $('.plus-sign').fadeIn();
        $('.services-text').fadeIn();
    }, 500);

}
```

The second part is where the animations happen. I'm using a toggle function to activate the animations. Occasionally the first 2 lines of the part commented as "Animate other containers" fails to occur.

```
$('.div-1').toggle(function() {
    // Animate this container
    $(this).animate({ "width": "830px" }, 501);
    $('.graphic-1').animate({"height": "200px"}).attr("src", "images/svg-icons/1.svg");
    $(this).children('.graphic-wrapper').animate({ "width": "275px"}, 500);
    $(this).find('.services-text').show();
    $(this).children('.services-content').fadeIn(2000);

    // Animate other containers
    $(this).siblings().children('.services-content').hide();
    $('.plus-sign').hide();
    $(this).siblings().animate({ "width": "90px" }, 500);
    $(this).siblings().children('.graphic-wrapper').animate({ "width": "90px" }, 500);
    $(this).siblings().children('.graphic-wrapper').children('.services-text').hide();
    $('.graphic-2').animate({"height": "60px"}).attr("src", "images/svg-icons/2b.svg");
    $('.graphic-3').animate({"height": "60px"}).attr("src", "images/svg-icons/3b.svg");
    $('.graphic-4').animate({"height": "60px"}).attr("src", "images/svg-icons/4b.svg");

    // Show new content
    setTimeout( function() { 
        $('.dropdown-default').fadeOut('fast');
        $('.dropdown-2').fadeOut('fast');
        $('.dropdown-3').fadeOut('fast');
        $('.dropdown-4').fadeOut('fast');
        setTimeout( function() {
            $('.dropdown-1').fadeIn();
            $('.dropdown-info').fadeIn();
        }, 500);
    }, 600);
}, function() {
    if ( $('.div-1').css("width") == open ) {
        closeService();
    } else {
        // REPEAT THE FIRST BLOCK OF CODE ABOVE
    }
});
```

The script works in most instances, but when I'm clicking through it during testing it'll break for the reasons I listed above and I can't identify why. I haven't managed to figure out if there's some kind of pattern of clicking that causes it to break either. Any ideas of what may be causing this?

Comment: setTimeout - At first glance , what jumps out is that your setTimeouts are not assigned to a variable. **window.timer = setTimeout( ..** /  so before you start another timer you can clear it -  **clearTimeout(timer)** - in case it is has not completed, you don't want to start another

Comment: Could you provide the html code, or even better, a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: ^ might not be THE answer , but good practice nontheless

Comment: Before doing the .animate try to use .stop(false,true).animate() etc... This might be the problem. have a look here http://api.jquery.com/stop/